# Note in R CRAN check -- * checking top-level files ... NOTE File README.md cannot be checked without ‘pandoc’ being installed

Tags: r, package, pandoc, cran

I am checking my R package for CRAN submission, but there is one NOTE that I cannot get rid of. I googled it but seems this NOTE is not common thus I didn't find much useful information. Could any one provide me with a solution? Below is part of the output from `R CMD check --as-cran`.

```
* using R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
* using platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
* using session charset: UTF-8
* using option ‘--as-cran’
...
...
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking top-level files ... NOTE
File README.md cannot be checked without ‘pandoc’ being installed.
* checking for left-over files ... OK
* checking index information ... OK
```

Comment: Well, do you have pandoc installed?

Comment: [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/341295/install-pandoc-required-for-docverter) you'll find a discussion of how to install pandoc.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, thanks. So we can assume that CRAN server also has that installed when checking the R package. Am I correct?

Comment: @Nussig. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You can also add the README files to your `.Rbuildignore` file (numerous examples of that all across github)

Comment: @hrbrmstr, thanks. That's good to know.

Answer (score 3):

You can install pandoc from within R using `install.pandoc()` from the `installr` package.